can not connect to mysql with php code | used docker
i use WordPress want to use docker and deploy on a server
problem is i can use WordPress but when want to use duplicator to transfer my site errored that can not connect to MySQL
problem is wordpress itself can connect to db but other php codes can not
docker-compose.yml file with following code
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite


  php:
    image: php:7.4
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    networks:
      - wpsite

networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:

also i write a PHP code to test can connect to db but also also in path of localhost:8000/test.php got error 500 status code
if i delete codes that connect to db 500 error code will removed and work normal

A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.
